# Evaluate javascript on every dynamically loaded nested iFrames using Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Before I start describing my problem I just want to give a heads-up that all the pages, iFrames etc. are hosted locally on my PC. And that I have used `page.setBypassCSP(true)` to temporarily disable any origin based restrictions.

Here we go, I have a webpage which embeds an iFrame and that iFrame may embed another one (and the list can go on...). Some of the deeper iFrames may be appended to the body of it's parent via Javascript e.g. `document.body.appendChild` inside a `setTimeout(..., 3000)` which kind of simulates a dynamic iframe load. I want to know what is the best way to evaluate a script source on all of these iFrames. I tried using `page.on('framenavigated', ...)` but this only works for the page's immediate child frame(s).

I tried recursively iterating through all the frames in the page using `page.frames()` but that only works for iFrames that are available at the time when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

I'm looking for a way to listen to all the `framenavigated` events fired by all the nested iFrames even for the ones that loaded dynamically at any point of time, after the page is loaded. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have tried listening to events using `page.on('frameattached', ...)` and `page.on('framedetached', ...)` but that also doesn't let me list all iFrames.

Comment: Could you not use `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` to wait until everything is loaded and then [recursively iterate over all frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55994534/5627599)?

Comment: If you think of a situation when a use clicks a button and an XHR call is fired and based on the response an Iframe is appended to the body. And the user can click the button at his will. So listening for an event makes more sense in such a situation.